# How can I upload a certificate to windows dev center account settings?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-dev-center

I'm following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx) tutorial in order to setup an authenticated web service to send push notifications. I have signed in [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows) into Dev Center. If I go to the Dashboard and then to Account settings I do not see a Certificates section where I can upload a certificate. Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for way to upload certificate for Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS).

Click on your app. Select Services -> Push notifications and it will allow you to select certificate for app. Please see below screenshot

[image]